# Prove that P(A) ≤ P(B) + P(A|¬B)

Tags: probability

I'm supposed to prove that P(A) ≤ P(B) + P(A|¬B). I already figured out that, to get to P(A|¬B) i have to use:

P(A) = P(A and B) or P(A and ¬B)

after that i am replacing P(A and B) with P(A|B)*P(B)
also i am replacing P(A and ¬B) with P(A|¬B)*P(¬B)

after that im stuck with:

P(A) = P(A|B)*P(B) + P(A|¬B)*P(¬B)

I think now i have to get rid of P(A|B) at the beginning of the formula and (¬B) at the end, but can not figure out how to.

Comment: Note that $P(A\mid B)\leq 1$ and $P(\neg B)\leq 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show this use that the probability measure is less or equal to $1$.
$$P(A)=P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^\complement)=P(A|B)P(B)+P(A|B^\complement)P(B^\complement)\leq P(B)+P(A|B^\complement).
$$

Comment: I understand, but to get into this deeper - what does this probability measure is meant to be in this formula. I already checked but couldnt find any further information. Doesnt every probability have to be between 0 and 1? Maybe im thinking this to simple, but i really want to understand the correlation between this two.

Comment: Yes, every probabilitymeasure takes values between $0$ and $1$. But I don't understand what you mean by ' what does this probability measure is meant to be...'. The probability measure is arbitrary. The inequality holds for every probability measure as long as $P(B)>0$ and $P(B^\complement)>0$ hold.

Comment: hmmm to specify it more clearly i would ask - What is this probability measure? and why can i use it get to this last formula? I hope i am not overdoing it with my questions, im very new to this topic so please bear with me.

Comment: The probability measure can be anything you want, as long as it meets the definition of a  probability measure. For example it could describe the throw of a coin or a dice or how the weather will be tomorrow. But it doesn't matter what it is, since we only used properties of the definition of a probability measure. What it describes in the end is not a question a mathematician has to deal with, the user has always to give this answer.